# How to perform PHP redirection to the previous directory?

Tags: php

In my program I have a file called `main` which contains subdirectory called `sub`. Inside the subdirectory `sub` I have a file from where I want to redirect the user to the previous directory. I tried using

```
header("location: ../")
```

Also,

```
header('location:'.dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])."'");
```

but none of them worked for me. What is the solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dirname(__FILE__)` with `explode()` to achieve the previous directory:

```
# get current directory
$currentPath = dirname(__FILE__); 
$pathArr = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $currentPath);
# remove last el of array (current directory)
array_pop($pathArr); 

header('Location:'. implode('/', $pathArr));
```

Comment: treyBake it is still not working it says page not found

Comment: @Niyojoli how are you executing the file?